# Book about a British boy from a futuristic world

Tags: story-identification, technology, computers, advertisements, future

It's a story about:

- a boy called "Jay"
- he has a sister who is apparently a hacker and can block the WiFi in specific places
- and a mom who works for rich people
- and a dad that works in a neighborhood for rich people to clean up their streets or something
- the boy jay is in a futuristic world where there are ads everywhere like you can't tell if they're people or not
- it's set in England
- there's some big digital back Dino monster that attacks people and takes their money
- there's a digital dog that wants him to buy (basically another ad tugging on his emotional strings to keep him buying from their company)
- there's his friend Robin I think and he helped him and let him on his strong private WiFi server to save him from the digital hack monster guy who was stealing everyone's credit. He also has an ad blocker
- and then the school announced that they wouldn't be coming into school now and do all their learning online and Jay felt sad about that (the school has their own and block free WiFi zone, I think, so no ads allowed)

I read it as an extract in school but it's actually kinda interesting

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?